# Stripping characters using a regex fails using literal characters with diacritics, apostrophes, accents, and the like

Tags: java, regex, unicode, character-encoding, replaceall

I'm trying to generate a string that conforms to a pattern in an XSD. To strip any characters that don't appear in the XSD pattern, I'm doing the following (the `replaceAll` call literally copied from my code):

```
import java.lang.String;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("Führ");
    }

    private static void test( String name ) {
        name = name.toUpperCase( );
        name = name.replaceAll (
            "[^A-ZА-ЯΑ-ΩÄÀÁÂÃÅǍĄĂÆÇĆĈČĎĐÐÈÉÊËĚĘĜĢĞĤÌÍÎÏĴĶĹĻŁĽÑŃŇÖÒÓÔÕŐØŒŔŘẞŚŜŞŠȘŤŢÞȚÜÙÚÛŰŨŲŮŴÝŸŶŹŽŻ, '\\-–]", 
            ""
        );
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

This fragment runs fine, and prints out "FÜHR". However, in the environment I'm running on, with exactly the same `replaceAll` statement, the `replaceAll` call removes the `Ü` character and prints out `FHR` with data (i.e. the name) coming from a database and starting with the same characters as in the code snippet ("Führ").

I'm puzzled... what could be the cause, and how can I fix this?

---

PS: The encoding of the source file is UTF-8 (Eclipse .settings: `encoding//<<<src-path>>>.java=UTF-8`)

Comment: Try setting LC_ALL=C.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks to be a Unix setting... I'll try to find an equivalent for Windoze environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tried using `Locale.setDefault( Locale.ROOT );`... no change.

Comment: What is _"in the environment I'm running on"_ in detail?

Comment: Print out the numerical value of the character in both cases to see the difference.

Comment: @JimGarrison Added info on environment

Comment: @JimGarrison Added the byte form of the name in uppercase, and the Ü. They differ as one would imagine. The symbols do look the same on screen, must be that the same character can be encoded differently?

Comment: I think the regex is wrong, in the sense that I am only matching specific code points, and not characters that are combined (U + ¨).

Comment: i test with `.replaceAll("[ÄÀÁÂÃÅǍĄĂÆÇĆĈČĎĐÐÈÉÊËĚĘĜĢĞĤÌÍÎÏĴĶĹĻŁĽÑŃŇÖÒÓÔÕŐØŒŔŘẞŚŜŞŠȘŤŢÞȚÜ\\,\\'\\–-]", "")` and it worked.

Comment: @amir110 Thank you for trying this out :). I can attest that in some cases it works, and in some it doesn't. I'm seeing a problem where the string is coming from a database, and where the `ü` is encoded differently from the literal `"ü"` in a Java String. I'm fiddling around with normalizing the string from the database, and having the regex starting with `"(?U)"`, but I'm not there yet...

Comment: Do you just want to replace all non-letters?

Comment: @Bohemian No, remove any letter that does not appear in the regex as in the question (i.e. everything except the long string in the regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly, when matching characters with diacritics, apostrophes, accents, and the like, one should specify the characters using the unicode single code point.

For instance, for the à character, the regex should specify `\u00E0` and not the literal `à`. The reason being, that the à character can be encoded in two ways:

- The à character as a single-code-point (the literal à)
- The à character as a double-code-point (a followed by the accent `)

Specifying the unicode code point `\u00E0` in the regex will match both encodings of à. Specifying the literal `à` in the regex will only match the way that character is encoded in your code fragment, and if it is encoded as a double-code-point, it will not match the single-code-point version of the same character.

Rewriting the regex using the unicode single code points solved the problem. For the Ü character as in the question, the regex should specify `\u00DC`. This matches both the single-code-point and double-code-point encoding of Ü.

I found the information that led to a solution here: [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters and Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) (paragraph: *Matching a Specific Code Point*).